# Leaflet map not loading tiles

Tags: javascript, png, leaflet

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>OpenTTD Map</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://npmcdn.com/leaflet@1.0.0-rc.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/leaflet@1.0.0-rc.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 1600px; height: 900px"></div>
    <script>

        var tile_url = 'http://dev.ruun.nl/zelf/openttd/tiles/map_{x}_{y}.png';

        var map = L.map('map', {
          maxZoom: 20,
          minZoom: 20,
          crs: L.CRS.Simple
        }).setView([0, 0], 20);
        //65409x32839
        var southWest = map.unproject([0, 32839], map.getMaxZoom());
        var northEast = map.unproject([65409, 0], map.getMaxZoom());
        map.setMaxBounds(new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast));
        L.tileLayer(tile_url, {
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; Ieuan\'s OpenTTD World',    
            continuousWorld: true,
            tileSize: 256
        }).addTo(map);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

For some reason my tiles aren't loading, map is just showing grey. They're not being downloaded by browser and I'm not getting any error messages

The tiles are 256x256 parts of a 65409x32839 screenshot

URL to view is http://dev.ruun.nl/zelf/openttd/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to explicitly specify that your Tile Layer [`maxZoom`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#tilelayer-maxzoom) option is 20, otherwise you get the default value of `18`, which prevents your tiles from being called at your only zoom (`20`).

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/0654usix33JJ5HJ4EQT4?p=preview

Comment: It's good to remind that setting a `maxZoom` for the map does **not** override the [default `maxZoom` option in `TileLayer`s](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#tilelayer-maxzoom)

Comment: Thanks ghybs, I managed to get it all working on Leaflet's side of things